# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Order' not found on type mine.domain.OrderHistory

Tags: java, jsp, exception, properties

I am using jaxb to convert my xml to java beans. I have the orderhistory class which will have the list of orders. I am getting the bean in the jsp but when i try to use,
`<c:forEach items="${OrderHistory.Order}" var="orderInfo">` i am getting `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Order' not found on type mine.domain.OrderHistory` Here is my orderhistory.java,

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "totalPages",
    "order",
     })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "OrderHistory")
    public class OrderHistory
    implements Serializable
     {

private final static long serialVersionUID = -6026937020915831338L;

protected int totalPages;
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
protected List<Order> order;


public List<Order> getOrder() {
    if (order == null) {
        order = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }
    return this.order;
}

   OrderHistory oh = // i am populating it here 
   TypedProperty responseProperties = new TypedProperty();
responseProperties.put("OrderHistory",oh);
    setResponseProperties(responseProperties);
```

I am able to see the order list populated in the orderhistory bean in the java side but i am not able access it on the jsp. What am i doing wrong???

Comment: Just to verify - do you mean orderHistory or OrderHistory in your EL expression? I'm wondering if an attempt to access the method statically is being made.

Comment: @JamesB see my edit. I am using that in my java..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property name is order, not Order.

Comment: my mistake there was one other reference of `${OrderHistory.Order}` thats y the issue.. Thanks for answer..

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable "order" in small letters in OrderHistory
 class but you are trying to access variable  "Order".
Instead of  "${OrderHistory.Order}" can you try "${OrderHistory.order}"